# Combination of cards

Tags: combinatorics

> From a deck of 52 cards, how many five card poker hands can be formed
>   if there is a pair (two of the cards are the same number, and none of
>   the other cards are the same number)?

I believe you can pick out the first card by ${_4}C_2$, as there are 4 cards which would be the same number (as there are 4 suits). I would pick two from here.

From here on though, I am unsure. I believe it involves the numbers 48, 44, and 40, as after every picking you cannot have an identical number anywhere, so there would be 4 less to choose from. However, I don't believe I can just do $_{48}C_1 * _{44}C_1,..$ as I am not simply selecting 1 card from 48 and removing 4 random ones.

The answer is $1098240$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will use the notation $\binom{n}{r}$, which is more common among mathematicians,  where you write ${}_nC_r$.

The *kind* of card that we have a pair of can be chosen in $\binom{13}{1}$ ways. For each choice of kind, the actual cards can be chosen in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways.
(By *kind* we mean things like Ace, or $7$, or Queen.)

For each choice made so far, we now count the number of ways to pick the rest of the cards. The *kinds* of cards we have singletons of can be chosen in $\binom{12}{3}$ ways. For each such choice, the actual cards can be chosen in $4^3$ ways. This is because if, for example, we are to have a $7$, a $10$, and a Queen, the $7$ can be picked in $4$ ways, as can the $10$, as can the Queen.   The total number of one pair hands is therefore 
$$(13)\binom{4}{2}\binom{12}{3}4^3.$$
Compute. We get $1098240$.

Comment: Thank you. I'm just going to reiterate what I believe you mean here. The 13C1 ways are from Ace to King. From that, there are 4 suits from which we choose 2 of to get the pair. Now there are 12 numbers (say Ace to Queen) we can choose from. We choose 3 of these (2 have been chosen). For each of these three, there are 4 suits again. By the fundamental counting principle, there are then 4*4*4 ways to choose it (4 for each as there are 4 suits). Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, good summary, shorter than mine. The only thing I don't understand is your sentence "We choose $3$ of these ($2$ have been chosen)." The part in parentheses seems not relevant. Two **cards** have already been chosen, of the same kind, but that has nothing to do with choosing $3$ *kinds* of cards to have singletons in.

Comment: Yes, sorry, that's what I meant. Two __cards__ have been chosen, three more cards to choose from, and to determine that, choose three numbers (kinds) that each have 4 suits. By 'have singletons in', you simply mean just to have one of each kind of card, right?

Comment: Yes, I mean one of that kind.

Comment: Thank you for all your help! The connections to the problem was easy to make thanks to your answer.

Comment: Counting other standard types of poker hands uses the same principles. The only tricky one is two pairs, where it is all too easy to end up with an answer which is twice the correct one.

Comment: If you're still around - would it be just $13 * _{4}C_2 * 12 * _{4}C_2 * (11/1) * 4$? Which would give me $247 104$?

Comment: No, instead of your $(13)(12)$ we want $\binom{13}{2}$, half as much. If you use $(13)(12)$ you are implicitly, for example, counting two Kings and two $7$'s as different from two $7$'s and two Kings. The issue doesn't arise with Full house (three of a kind and two of another).

Comment: Right. The 13 is essentially $_{13}Cr_1$, right? So it wouldn't make sense to pick 1 from 13 types, then pick 1 from 12 types after because of your reasoning (it assumes they are different). You would just pick 2 from 13.